# SELECT query on xmltable

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, xquery, xmltable

I'm trying to perform a select query as follows, where I'm Passing a small xml as xmltype.

```
SELECT x.PO_STEP,x.INSTL_ID,X.INSTL_LOC_CODE from xmltable
(
  XMLNAMESPACES('namespace1' as "v20", 'namespace2' as "v201"),
'/v20:ProductionOrder/v201:ProductionOrderSteps/v201:ProductionOrderStep/v201:POStepDetails/v201:InstallationDetails/*[text()]'
PASSING xmltype(' <v20:ProductionOrder xmlns="***something***" xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v20="namespace1">

        <v201:ProductionOrderSteps xmlns:v201="namespace2">
          <v201:ProductionOrderStep>
            <v201:POStepDetails>
              <v201:PO_STEP>1L</v201:PO_STEP>
              <v201:InstallationDetails>
                <v201:INSTL_ID>032</v201:INSTL_ID>
                <v201:INSTL_LOC_CODE>N</v201:INSTL_LOC_CODE>
              </v201:InstallationDetails>
              <v201:InstallationDetails>
                <v201:INSTL_ID>000</v201:INSTL_ID>
                <v201:INSTL_LOC_CODE />
              </v201:InstallationDetails>
              <v201:InstallationDetails>
                <v201:INSTL_ID>000</v201:INSTL_ID>
                <v201:INSTL_LOC_CODE />
              </v201:InstallationDetails>
              <v201:InstallationDetails>
                <v201:INSTL_ID>000</v201:INSTL_ID>
                <v201:INSTL_LOC_CODE />
              </v201:InstallationDetails>
            </v201:POStepDetails>
          </v201:ProductionOrderStep>
          <v201:ProductionOrderStep>
            <v201:POStepDetails>
              <v201:PO_STEP>1B</v201:PO_STEP>
              <v201:InstallationDetails>
                <v201:INSTL_ID>001</v201:INSTL_ID>
                <v201:INSTL_LOC_CODE>N</v201:INSTL_LOC_CODE>
              </v201:InstallationDetails>
              <v201:InstallationDetails>
                <v201:INSTL_ID>000</v201:INSTL_ID>
                <v201:INSTL_LOC_CODE />
              </v201:InstallationDetails>
              <v201:InstallationDetails>
                <v201:INSTL_ID>000</v201:INSTL_ID>
                <v201:INSTL_LOC_CODE />
              </v201:InstallationDetails>
            </v201:POStepDetails>
          </v201:ProductionOrderStep>
        </v201:ProductionOrderSteps>
      </v20:ProductionOrder>')

 COLUMNS
 PO_STEP VARCHAR2(20) PATH './parent::*/parent::*/v201:PO_STEP',
 INSTL_ID VARCHAR2(30) PATH '//v201:INSTL_ID',
 INSTL_LOC_CODE VARCHAR2(30) PATH '//v201:INSTL_LOC_CODE'
)x
```

but I am getting the following result

```
    PO_STEP     INSTL_ID  INSTL_LOC_CODE
        1L      null        null
        1L      null        null
        1L      null        null
        1L      null        null
        1L      null        null
        1B      null        null
        1B      null        null
        1B      null        null
        1B      null        null
```

I am not able to understand what is wrong with the Xpath, whether the xpath is being passed wrongly alongside the columns or the xpath written on top is wrong.
I am using oracle sql developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the xpath

`/v20:ProductionOrder/v201:ProductionOrderSteps/v201:ProductionOrderStep/v201:POStepDetails/v201:InstallationDetails/*[text()]`

to

`/v20:ProductionOrder/v201:ProductionOrderSteps/v201:ProductionOrderStep/v201:POStepDetails/v201:InstallationDetails`

To get the first occurrence add `[1]` in the end like :

`/v20:ProductionOrder/v201:ProductionOrderSteps/v201:ProductionOrderStep/v201:POStepDetails/v201:InstallationDetails[1]`

AND

Change

`./parent::*/parent::*/v201:PO_STEP`

to

`./parent::*/v201:PO_STEP`

The result will be :

```
1L  032 N
1L  000 
1L  000 
1L  000 
1B  001 N
1B  000 
1B  000
```

For the first occurrence only, the result will be :

```
1L 032 N
1B 001 N
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.

And what if I need to just see the first occurance of each <v201:InstallationDetails>, i.e., the output must look like as follows

1L  032 N
1B  001 N

Comment: I edited the answer on how to get only the first occurrence.

Comment: @ArpanMona Could you upvote and accept the answer. If you don't do so, others who are looking for similar answers may not find it useful. Thanks !